# Azure VM password reset

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, forgot-password

I have 2 Azure Virtual machines in 1 network and Domain. My Domain Users/Administrators password expired and i forgot built-in login/password for these VM's.

I tried like 30 times on (both VM), to change/reset password of users by using AzureVMAccessExtension, with correct new (long and difficult) password.

```
PS script:
$vmName = "" 
$serviceName = "" 
$newAdminUserName = "" 
$newAdminPassword = "" 

$vmc = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -Name $vmName 
$vmc | Set-AzureVMAccessExtension -UserName $newAdminUserName -Password $newAdminPassword 
$vmc | Update-AzureVM
Restart-AzureVM -ServiceName $serviceName -Name $vmName
```

Still cant login.

I even tried to run remote power shell script "Enable-PSSession", to change RDP policy, but the access was denied.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem several times before and what worked for me was to create a new user instead of trying to reset the old local administrator account.

Comment: I see. I tried this too with same result. And  i  should add user as "domain\username"? Or just "username".

Comment: just username. Not sure, but i think you also need to supply the parameter  -ReferenceName "VMAccessAgent" in your Set-AzureVMAccessExtension command.

Comment: Tried. I saw new user when i Get-AzureVmAcessExtension - but cant login via rdp :(

Comment: Double check if you are using the correct login prefixes. To explicit tell rdp to use a local account on a domain joined machine you have to use .\<username> instead of just the username. Try this.

Comment: Tried with .\Username and after i hit enter i get mycurrentLaptopAd\Username. I tried with all prefixes like "domain\machineName\DnsName" Is it possible, that something cached on my laptop?

Comment: It will show your laptop username yes, but it is supposed to work. Don't think it's cache. Maybe a group policy preventing login using the local accounts.

Comment: Hey, probably the problem is that i am trying to change built-in administrator on Domain Controller?

Comment: scripts like yours would change local accounts only not domain accounts. Your variable $newAdminUserName should be set to a username without the domain. I.e $newAdminUserName = "AzureAdmin". Then on RDP you have to use .\AzureAdmin as login

Comment: hey, not sure if you still have problems with this VM. Try this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2976864 to reset your password then use HOSTNAME\USERNAME and Password to login.

Comment: I always get a Deploy Failed when attempting to reset the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the password of all Classic VMs i.e. the VMs created via old ASM portal via going to [New ARM Azure Portal](http://portal.azure.com). Then find your VM on the Virtual Machines -Classic blade, and go to the settings and select Password Reset option. I have seen this to work even when PowerShell cmdlets fail for this particular operation.

For new VMs created via ARM portal, the support for password reset is not there in the portal but will be coming soon.